# I want to have a listview.builder with CircleAvatars that display the names, inside another listview.bilder

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I want to have a listview.builder with circle avatars inside my     listview.

```
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1Gjt.png

class Project {
final int id;
final String title;
final String description;
final String deadline;
final String subject;
final String days_left;
final List users;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and don't include sample json as an image. Can you add the ui code you already tried too?

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView.builder(

        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
          return CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
            child: Text(projects.users[index]['username']),
          );
        },
      ),
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Even though this may answer the question, there is no explanation of your code. Please update your answer to provide an explanation of what you are doing. Thanks!